# sed replace does not come up with my desired result

Tags: replace, sed

```
sudo sed -i 's!# dbdir /var/lib/munin!dbdir /var/lib/munin!g' /etc/munin/munin.conf    
sudo sed -i 's!localhost 127.0.0.0/8  ::1!all!g' /etc/munin/apache.conf
```

Why does `# dbdir /var/lib/munin` does not get replace with `dbdir /var/lib/munin`
and
why does `localhost 127.0.0.0/8  ::1` not get replaced with `all`?

```
sudo sed -i 's!# dbdir!dbdir!g' /etc/munin/munin.conf
```

gives a satisfactory result, only the localhost replacement question remaining.

Comment: Show us the relevant lines of your input files.

Comment: Maybe the input file contains TAB characters rather than spaces.

Comment: Are you doing this interactively or in a script? If interactive, are you getting error messages about history items not found? That's because `!` is the history prefix.

Comment: I replace delimeter / by ! so I did not have to worry about stuff like /\ all the time. Chose the wrong charactor?

Comment: Input is correct: sudo sed -i 's!localhost 127.0.0.0/8  ::1!all!g' /etc/munin/apache.conf

Comment: I am trying to automate this howto... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-munin-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's!# htmldir /var/cache/munin/www!htmldir /var/cache/munin/www!g' /etc/munin/munin.conf` works like a charme.

Comment: My vote is with @Barmar. If the file contains irregular whitespace, `sed` does not compensate for that. Try a regex like `[  ][  ]*` instead of a single space, where the brackets contain a space and a tab.

Comment: Actually, since the `!` is inside quotes, it won't be used as a history selector, so you're OK. Are you saying that your script works correctly for `htmldir`, but fails for `dbdir`? The only explanation is that the line in the input file doesn't match what you're putting in your `sed` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my munin.conf there are multiple space between `dbdir` and `/var/lib/munin` so unless you have exact info this replace would not work.
You search for only part of the text then replace the line:

```
awk '/dbdir/ {$0="dbdir /var/lib/munin"}1' /etc/munin/munin.conf > temp ; mv temp /etc/munin/munin.conf
```

or remove then `#` in front of the line

```
awk '/dbdir/ {sub(/^#/,x)}1' /etc/munin/munin.conf
```

EDIT:

```
awk '/Allow from local/ {sub(/localhost 127.0.0.0\/8 ::1/,"all")}1' /etc/munin/apache.conf
```

Comment: and what about... 'sudo sed -i 's!localhost 127.0.0.0/8  ::1!all!g' /etc/munin/apache.conf'

Comment: try `grep "localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1" /etc/munin/apache.conf` if this does not give any output, you have the text or space wrong.

Comment: 'grep "localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1"  etc/munin/apache.conf'
        _Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1_ It gives the correct output